# Invalid index 3, size is 3 Android

Tags: android

In my application I want to navigate left and right and change textView value while clicking on next and back button. But when the index is greater than the number of items I get a force close error. Here is my code.

```
    String[] seperated = imag;

        count_image = seperated.length-1;

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(seperated));

        pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()

        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

        .cacheOnDisc()

        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)

        .build();

        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);



        @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.boutton_slide_droite:


            focus_image = pager.getCurrentItem();

            //get current image index 

            focus_image++;


            //move to next record

            position++;

            System.out.println("focus_image_up:"+focus_image);


            if(focus_image<count_image){

                if(focus_image>=count_image){

                    focus_image=0;
                    pagerPosition=0;

                }else {


                    pager.setCurrentItem(focus_image);

                    disable_progress=true; 

                    System.out.println("focus_image up if ++: 

"+focus_image);



                        text_num.setText("No. "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNum());
                        text_name.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getNom());

                        text_team.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getTeam());
                        text_date.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getNaissance());

                    if 
(PostList.get(position).getNBVictoire().equals("1"))

                        text_victoires.setText("Victoire: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBVictoire());

                    else 
                        text_victoires.setText("Victoires: "+ PostList.get(focus_image).getNBVictoire());


                    if (PostList.get(focus_image).getNBCourse().equals("1"))

                        text_nomb.setText("Nombre de course: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBCourse());

                    else 

                        text_nomb.setText("Nombre de courses: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBCourse());

                }

            }else {

                pagerPosition=count_image;

                focus_image=count_image;
        }


            break;




         case R.id.boutton_slide_gauche:

             focus_image = pager.getCurrentItem();

             focus_image--;

            //move to previous record

            position--;


            if (focus_image>0){



                if (focus_image<=count_image) {

                    System.out.println("focus_image_down: if "+focus_image);


                    pager.setCurrentItem(focus_image);

                    disable_progress=true;

                    text_num.setText("No. "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNum());
                    text_name.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getNom());

                    text_team.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getTeam());

                    text_date.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getNaissance());


                    if (PostList.get(focus_image).getNBVictoire().equals("1"))

                            text_victoires.setText("Victoire: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBVictoire());

                    else 

                        text_victoires.setText("Victoires: "+ PostList.get(focus_image).getNBVictoire());


                    if (PostList.get(position).getNBCourse().equals("1"))

                        text_nomb.setText("Nombre de course: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBCourse());
                    else 
                        text_nomb.setText("Nombre de courses: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBCourse());


                }else {


                    pager.setCurrentItem(focus_image);

                    disable_progress=true;

                    text_num.setText("No. "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNum());


text_name.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getNom());


text_team.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getTeam());


text_date.setText(PostList.get(focus_image).getNaissance());


                    if 

(PostList.get(focus_image).getNBVictoire().equals("1"))

                        text_victoires.setText("Victoire: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBVictoire());

                    else 


                        text_victoires.setText("Victoires: "+ PostList.get(focus_image).getNBVictoire());


                    if 

(PostList.get(position).getNBCourse().equals("1"))


                        text_nomb.setText("Nombre de course: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBCourse());


                    else 


                        text_nomb.setText("Nombre de courses: "+PostList.get(focus_image).getNBCourse());



                }


            }else {

                focus_image=0;
                pagerPosition=0;

            }


            break;
}
```

and the error is

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3

Comment: 1. put ImagePagerAdapter here. 2. you are filling data from webservices?? if yes then check parsing code. 3. you are using multiple array in ImagePagerAdapter then you have to check size of all array is same or not. this all are possibility to get this error.

Answer (score 3):

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3` is enough to figure out the error. Nothing else is required.

If the size is `3`, you can access only till the index `2`. Increase the array/arraylist size to `4`, if you want to access the index `3`.

Comment: yes but it takes 0,1,2 only 3 doesn't exist. How can i test it whether it lies between internal and if it is >3 or more it reset the values ? A help Luffy : )

Comment: firstly, post the full stack trace and figure out where exactly its throwing the exception. Next, the logic you mentioned is good enough. wherever it gives that exception, just before that code piece, check if the `var` is less than 3, and if not, reset it to `0`.

Comment: Also, try to debug your code(by putting breakpoints) & put some loggers.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor cursor=FavouriteActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM FAVOURITE");
                    ArrayList<Integer> arrID=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                        arrID.add(cursor.getInt(0));
                    }

                    FavouriteActivity.sqLiteHelper.deleteData(arrID.get(position));
//                    FavouriteActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            });
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder=(ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Model_Favourite model_favourite=favouritelist.get(position);
        byte[] favouriteimage = model_favourite.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(favouriteimage,0,favouriteimage.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return row;











logcat:error
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.vbs.ladieskurti.FavouriteListAdapter$1.onClick(FavouriteListAdapter.java:79)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```